# Send Health Check report results through email

Tags: salesforcedx, tooling-api, singleemailmessage

I have a use case where I need to send the details of Health Check results through email by an automation.

1. I tried using SecurityHealthCheckRisks object to retrieve data and send it through SingleEmailMessage but it seems Health Check is a Tooling API object and don't know how to to utilize to send data through email.
2. I was also wondering if there is any automation possible which convert the particular Health Check webpage into a pdf and send to the email.
   Thanks